# Given symmetric $n\times n$ matrices $\sum_k A_k= I, \sum_k rank( A_k) = n$, then $A_i A_j = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given  symmetric $n\times n$ matrices $\sum_k A_k=  I, \sum_k rank( A_k) = n$, then $A_i A_j = 0$

I know the condition implies $Rank(A_i + A_j) = Rank(A_i) + Rank (A_j)$ which implies $Col(A_i) \cap Col (A_j) = \{0\}$. How could I continue this?

From the additional link in the comment, I know that $Col(A_i)$ is orthogonal to $Nul(A_i)$ also the same for $A_j$ since they are real symmetric. 
To show $A_i A_j = 0$, we want $Col(A_j) \subset Nul(A_i) \Leftrightarrow Col(A_j) \subset Col(A_i)^\perp$, but how can i get this from the fact that $Col(A_i) \cap Col (A_j) = \{0\}$

Comment: You probably want to require $i \neq j$. (No idea on how to solve this.)

Comment: Yes, $i\neq j$.

Comment: Related: [For a set of symmetric matrices $A_i$ of order p, show that if the sum of their ranks is p, $A_iA_j=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1461696)